# Node.js cannot view headers inside middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node.js restful API. The problem I am having is that I am not sure why I am not able to see the request headers inside the middleware `route.use()`, however, it is visible inside get method `router.get('/',function(req,res){}).`

Can you someone please why is this case or what do I have to do get it visible inside

```
router.use(function(req,res,next){  next();});
```

Comment: You can also get header inside `router.use(function(req,res,next){  next();});` show your full code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like his

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
 console.log(req.headers['header_name']);
  if (!req.headers['header_name']) return next('router')
  next()
})
```

To skip the rest of the router’s middleware functions, call next('router') to pass control back out of the router instance.